# How to search for a vector in a matrix in C++ and which algorithm?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix and a vector given by. How can I perform a search algorithm like binary search to return the index?
Example:

```
const int V_SIZE = 10,H_SIZE = 7;
   int a1[V_SIZE][H_SIZE] = {
                                {1,2,0,0,0,0,0},
                                {1,3,0,0,0,0,0},
                                {2,2,4,0,0,0,0},
                                {2,2,6,0,0,0,0},
                                {3,2,4,7,0,0,0},
                                {4,1,3,5,9,0,0},
                                {4,1,4,6,8,0,0},
                                {4,2,3,4,7,0,0},
                                {5,2,3,5,7,8,0},
                                {6,1,3,4,5,7,10}
                            }; // sorted
  int a2 [H_SIZE] = {4,1,3,5,9,0,0};
```

Perform a search for the vector a2 in the matrix a1 and the return value is 6
Thank a lot

Comment: welcome to stack, rule is simple you show us your effort and we point out the mistake, No one will solve the entire problem for you here

Comment: With an initial index of 0, wouldn't the answer in your example be 5? Will the matrix always be sorted?

Comment: Yes, if the initial index is 0 the answer is 5. It is just an example. The first column is sorted ascending for binary search, the 2nd column is sorted ascending too base on the the 1st column value and so on

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 2D `std::array` in combination with `std::lower_bound`:

```
  const int V_SIZE = 10,H_SIZE = 7;
  std::array<std::array<int, H_SIZE>, V_SIZE> a1 {
                                {{{1,2,0,0,0,0,0}},
                                {{1,3,0,0,0,0,0}},
                                {{2,2,4,0,0,0,0}},
                                {{2,2,6,0,0,0,0}},
                                {{3,2,4,7,0,0,0}},
                                {{4,1,3,5,9,0,0}},
                                {{4,1,4,6,8,0,0}},
                                {{4,2,3,4,7,0,0}},
                                {{5,2,3,5,7,8,0}},
                                {{6,1,3,4,5,7,10}}
                            }}; // sorted

  std::array<int, H_SIZE> a2 {{4,1,3,5,9,0,0}};

  int idx = std::lower_bound(std::begin(a1), std::end(a1), a2) - std::begin(a1);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4772c41fc1c66b0d)

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is sorted on the first number, you could use binary search to find an *approximate* index. You then have to go back until you find the first row starting with the same number as in the vector, as well as forward to find the last row starting with the same number. Then you loop over the vector, searching for a match for the second, third, etc. number in the range of rows you have.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this using std::array?

```
template <int HSIZE>
bool operator<(const std::array<int, HSIZE> &lhs, const std::array<int, HSIZE> &rhs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HSIZE; i++)
        if (lhs[i] != rhs[i])
            return lhs[i] < rhs[i];
    return false;
}

std::array<int, 7> a1[] = 
{
    { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 2, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 3, 2, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 4, 1, 3, 5, 9, 0, 0 },
    { 4, 1, 4, 6, 8, 0, 0 },
    { 4, 2, 3, 4, 7, 0, 0 },
    { 5, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 0 },
    { 6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10 } 
};

void search(void)
{
    std::array<int, 7> a2 = { 4, 1, 3, 5, 9, 0, 0 };
    std::array<int, 7> *a1_end = a1 + sizeof(a1) / sizeof(std::array<int, 7>);
    std::array<int, 7> *it = std::lower_bound(a1, a1_end, a2);

}
```

Comment: If you're using `std::array`, why not a `std::array` of `std::array` objects for the matrix? Would make the size-calculation in the second step of `search` a little easier. :)